# No muestra marcador de google maps

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

Buen dia!

Espero puedan auxiliarme, el archivo php me muestra el mapa de google con la latitud y longitud correctas, estos datos los trae de MySQL. Si se visualiza el mapa segun estos datos, solo hay un DETALLE que no muestra el marcador(indicador) en el mapa.  Anexo el codigo que tengo.. Gracias!

```js
<?php
if($data->latitud=="" && $data->longitud==""){
 $data->latitud="27.470182279368984";
 $data->longitud="-99.50761556625366";
}else{


}
?>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $data->latitud; ?>, <?php echo $data->longitud; ?>);
var marker = new Array();
var infowindow;
function initialize(){
 var mapProp = {
   center:myCenter,
   zoom:16,
   mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   /*map.removeMarker();
   map.clearMarkers();*/
    placeMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

// para poner un marcador
function placeMarker(location) {
 if (!marker || !marker.setPosition) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,

   });
  } else {
    marker.setPosition(location);
  }
   
if (!!infowindow && !!infowindow.close) {
    infowindow.close();
  }
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Latitud: ' + location.lat() + '<br>Longitud: ' + location.lng()
  });
  infowindow.open(map, marker);

  $("#latitud").val(location.lat());
  $("#longitud").val(location.lng());
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Error:

> El marcador se agrega solo al hacer `click` en el mapa y le estas indicando que las coordenadas sean relativas a la posición donde el usuario hizo `click`.

Solución:

Llama `placeMarker` inmediatamente después de crear el mapa e indícale que sus coordenadas sean `myCenter`.

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
if($data->latitud=="" && $data->longitud==""){
    $data->latitud="27.470182279368984";
    $data->longitud="-99.50761556625366";
}else{


}
?>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $data->latitud; ?>, <?php echo $data->longitud; ?>);
var marker = new Array();
var infowindow;
function initialize(){
    var mapProp = {
    center:myCenter,
    zoom:16,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
  placeMarker(myCenter);
}

// para poner un marcador
function placeMarker(location) {
 if (!marker || !marker.setPosition) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,

   });
  } else {
    marker.setPosition(location);
  }

if (!!infowindow && !!infowindow.close) {
    infowindow.close();
  }
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Latitud: ' + location.lat() + '<br>Longitud: ' + location.lng()
  });
  infowindow.open(map, marker);

  $("#latitud").val(location.lat());
  $("#longitud").val(location.lng());
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

[Demo aquí](http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/tq91-zpnw)

Answer (score 0):

Remueve solo addlistener y coloca placeMarker(event.latLng) si quieres agregar eventos al marcador deberias revisa la documentacion oficial

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=es-419

```js
<?php
if($data->latitud=="" && $data->longitud==""){
 $data->latitud="27.470182279368984";
 $data->longitud="-99.50761556625366";
}else{


}
?>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $data->latitud; ?>, <?php echo $data->longitud; ?>);
var marker = new Array();
var infowindow;
function initialize(){
 var mapProp = {
   center:myCenter,
   zoom:16,
   mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);

  placeMarker(event.latLng);
 
}

// para poner un marcador
function placeMarker(location) {
 if (!marker || !marker.setPosition) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,

   });
  } else {
    marker.setPosition(location);
  }
   
if (!!infowindow && !!infowindow.close) {
    infowindow.close();
  }
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Latitud: ' + location.lat() + '<br>Longitud: ' + location.lng()
  });
  infowindow.open(map, marker);

  $("#latitud").val(location.lat());
  $("#longitud").val(location.lng());
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```